# Google Drive analytics - who download what

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I have the G-Suite for business, and I have a directory where I put some data about the company. The directory is private, and only some of my colleagues has the access.
I'd like to know who download/watch what. Is that possibile? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On a directory level you can just see major activities: edit/delete/copy/change of permission.

On a single "file" level you can click on `Tools --> Activity dashboard` to see who and when viewed that file but there is no way to track down the downloads.

More details here: [View activity & file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?visit_id=636746779844414338-2215526039&rd=1)